# Get the value of span through jquery

Tags: jquery

How to fetch the value of span through click on radio button. I preferred `$(this)` on click give the value of its Span text. Here is my code. Give me some advice. Thanks in advance

```
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 pad'>
  <input type='radio' name='test' value='' id='radio_btn'>
</div>

<div class='col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 pad'>
  <span>Option_1</span>
</div>

$('#radio_btn').on('click', function(e){
alert($(this).find('span').text())
});
```

Comment: Your code doesn't include any javavscript you have done ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no span inside the div where the radio button is. You can use this. Check jsfiddle as well.

```
$('#radio_btn').on('click', function(){
    alert($('.pad').find('span').text());
});

https://jsfiddle.net/31gqgc7n/2/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='test']").click(function(){
        $("span").each(function(){
            alert($(this).text());
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nhaav8pp/) with a functional example

Answer (score 0):

Actually, 'this' inside your function is $('#radio_btn'), so there is no span inside input and cannot be. Try this:

```
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 pad'>
    <input type='radio' name='test' value='' id='radio_btn'>
</div>

<div class='col-md-11 col-sm-11 col-xs-11 pad'>
     <span id="my_span">Option_1</span>
</div>

$('#radio_btn').on('click', function(e){
   alert($('#my_span').text());
});
```